# Instant messaging ping

Tags: chat, instant-messaging

I'm working on a project 'Instant Messaging' which works totally on UDP. I would like if there is any good tutorial regarding this. Also can anyone explain how does the client inform the server that it is up without using another port.

Answer (score 0):

Just take any tutorial on socket programming for your favourite language. Informing the server the client is up can be achieved by a simple Hello message.